# Finding Locus of a point under given condition.

Tags: geometry

**Problem**

Let **P** be the variable point on a circle **C** and **Q** is a fixer point on the outside of **C**. **R** is a point in **PQ** dividing it in the ratio **p:q** ,where **p>0** and **q>0** are fixed. Then what will be the locus of **R**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It' s a circle. 
Assume a circle $x^2+y^2=r^2 without loss of generality$.
A point on circle:
(r cos t, r sin t).
Let the ratio is k:1 where k=p/q
Then coordinates of dividing point are:
$(x,y)=
(\frac {kx_0+r cos t} {k+1} , \frac {ky_0+r sin t} {k+1} )$
Where $(x_0,y_0) $ are coordinates of Q.
Then eliminate t:
$(x(k+1)-kx_0)^2+(y(k+1)-ky_0)^2=r^2$ which is equation of circle.

Comment: Thanks. I was almost there.